# pub/sub : how can I use pub sub to check message in any email account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I am new to pub/sub on GCP and have some difficulties on understanding some concepts. So if I want to get email every time I have new message in my mailbox, can I use Pub/Sub for that? How the push notification work in that case? I understand the subscriber concepts but I have some difficulties in the publisher concepts. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Although I am not familiar with the Gmail API (I am specialized mainly in GCP), a quick read over the documentation can provide some really useful insights about this topic. Also, as per your question, I think your doubts are more related to Pub/Sub itself, rather than Gmail API, so let me try to clarify some things for you.

I can see in the Gmail API documentation, that you can [configure Gmail to send push notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) using Cloud Pub/Sub topics, in such a way that Gmail sends *publish* requests to a Pub/Sub topic whenever a mailbox update matches the configuration you established. Although I cannot get into much details about this part of the scenario, from the documentation I understand that the way to configure the Gmail push notifications is to make a [`watch()` request](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch) with the configuration you want and pointing a Pub/Sub topic that you should have previously created. Once this is set (and also permissions are correctly configured), Gmail would keep publishing mailbox message updates for a period of 7 days (after a week, you have to re-call `watch()`).

In order to receive notifications, you can now forget completely about the Gmail API, and you can focus on Pub/Sub. You should create a Pub/Sub subscription (using either [Pull or Push configuration](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber), depending on your requirements), so that your client (wherever and whatever it is) receives the Pub/Sub messages that work as a notification. You may have to acknowledge the messages so that they are not retried, too.

---

As a side note, given that you mentioned that the Pub/Sub subscriber concepts are more or less clear to you, and you would like to know more about publishing, let me share with you some links that may come in handy for a better understanding of the environment:

- [Pub/Sub main concepts](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/architecture#the_basics_of_a_publishsubscribe_service).
- [Typical Pub/Sub flow](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview#concepts).
- [General guide for Pub/Sub publishers](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher).

In the scenario you are presenting (Gmail notifications using Pub/Sub), you would have to create a topic (with the name you want, let's name it *gmail_topic*), and the Gmail API would be your *publisher*. What the `watch()` method would be doing, behind the scenes, is calling the [`publish()` method](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/publish) to send messages (containing information about mailbox updates) to your topic *gmail_topic*. Messages are passed to Pub/Sub subscriptions (which you can create and bind to the *gmail_topic*), and they retained in each of the subscriptions for 7 days (the maximum [retention period](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber)) until you consume and acknowledge them.